# Combine two 2d arrays and have duplicate rows removed

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, array-merge

How do I create a new multidimensional array by merging two arrays and removing any duplicate rows.

First array:

```
[
    0 => ["id" => "0001", "name" => "sample name 1"],
    1 => ["id" => "0002", "name" => "sample name 2"],
    3 => ["id" => "0003", "name" => "sample name 3"]
]
```

Second Array:

```
[
    0 => ["id" => "0002", "name" => "sample name 2"],
    1 => ["id" => "11323", "name" => "blah blah"]
]
```

The desired result is:

```
[
    ["id" => "0001", "name" => "sample name 1"],
    ["id" => "0002", "name" => "sample name 2"],
    ["id" => "0003", "name" => "sample name 3"]
    ["id" => "11323", "name" => "blah blah"]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
$array1 = Array(
        0 => Array("id" => "0001","name" => "sample name 1"),
        1 => Array("id" => "0002","name" => "sample name 2"),
        3 => Array("id" => "0003","name" => "sample name 3"));

$array2 = Array(
        0 => Array("id" => "0002","name" => "sample name 2"),
        1 => Array("id" => "11323","name" => "blah blah"));

$output = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", array_merge($array1,$array2))));

var_dump($output);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '0001' (length=4)
      'name' => string 'sample name 1' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '0002' (length=4)
      'name' => string 'sample name 2' (length=13)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '0003' (length=4)
      'name' => string 'sample name 3' (length=13)
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => string '11323' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'blah blah' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reduce your rows of data to be serialized strings to check for uniqueness.  Just call `array_udiff()` on the second array to remove first array rows from it, then merge that result with the first array.  `array_udiff()` is optimized under the hood because it uses a sorting algorithm to compare data -- in this way, it is more performant than making brute-force iterations of `in_array()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/r2oh0))

```
$array1 = [
    0 => ["id" => "0001", "name" => "sample name 1"],
    1 => ["id" => "0002", "name" => "sample name 2"],
    3 => ["id" => "0003", "name" => "sample name 3"]
];

$array2 = [
    0 => ["id" => "0002", "name" => "sample name 2"],
    1 => ["id" => "11323", "name" => "blah blah"]
];

var_export(
    array_merge($array1, array_udiff($array2, $array1, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b))
);
```

---

Because whole rows are being compared, you can also merge the arrays and use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag with `array_unique()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iPLJN))

```
var_export(
    array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2), SORT_REGULAR)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize each subarray, use `array_unique`, then unserialize back:

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
foreach($arr as &$a) {
    $a = serialize($a);
}
$arr = array_values(array_unique($arr));
foreach($arr as &$a) {
    $a = unserialize($a);
}
```